# Есть ли хорошая книга по Xml на русском языке (не позднее 2010 года)?

Tags: xml, книги, xslt

Есть ли хорошая книга по Xml на русском языке (не позднее 2010 года)?

Comment: >> Просто единственная хорошая книга аж 2001 А что с тех пор изменилось? Новых версий XML вроде не наблюдалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из более или менее свежих - "**XML И XSLT. Современные технологии обработки данных для ВЕБ**". Только это не книга, а видеокурс.

> не позднее 20010 года

Улыбнуло ))

Comment: От специалиста чтоли?)

Comment: От него родимого.) За последний год, так точно ничего свежего не попадалось. Хотя я не особо и рыскал в поисках, но всё же...

Comment: Уже скачад, спасибо. Просто единственная хорошая книга аж 2001 года(

Comment: Современные технологии? wtf?